# Autocorrelation function of an image before and after zero padding

Tags: matlab, math, signals

I would like to ask you a question, maybe trivial but actually, I'm a little bit confused.

Given a B&w imagine, my aim is to evaluate the autocorrelation function.
By following the approach described in [this example](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/67348-autocorr2d):

```
I=double(I); %convert to double
I=I-mean(I(:)); %subtract mean
I=I/sqrt(sum(I(:).^2)); %normalize magnitude
fft_I=fft2(I); %compute fft2
A=real(fftshift(ifft2(fft_I.*conj(fft_I)))); %compute autocorrelation
```

I obtain a function which gives the values of the autocorrelation related to the half domain of my image (along x as well as along y)

After some research, if I correctly understood, in order to obtain the autocorrelation function related to the entire domain, by following the above-mentioned procedure I have to zero-pad my image by adding zeros. I have done this and the obtained autocorrelation function is the same as the one obtained by using the Matlab command `xcorr2` (it should be a signal that I didn't make mistakes).

However, the correlation functions obtained by following the procedure in the link (no zero-pad) and the one obtained with the zero-pad are different in the same domain.

I expected that the two correlation functions were same... should they be the same or is correct that they are different?
What am I not getting?

Comment: How much different? Also post code using one of the sample images in matlab and your xcorr2 code.

Answer (score 1):

Note that when you compute the cross-correlation by multiplication in the Fourier domain, the image is assumed periodic. For a given shift, the parts of the image that doesn't overlap the image domain is wrapped around and comes back into the image domain on the other side.

When padding with zeros, the image domain becomes larger. If enough padding is applied, there is no shift for which the original image wraps around and comes back into the original image domain on the other side.

Thus, it is to be expected that the results are different even in the same domain. The further out from the origin you go, the more these two auto-correlation functions will differ.

Comment: @chris thank you for answering and editing my question. 
Since as you said the outcomes of the autocorrelation function obtained by the FFT and the FFT+zero-padding could be different, is there a way to obtain the same result in the same between the two ways?  I'm asking that because I believe that the correct outcomes useful for my case of study are the ones provided by the FFT without zero-padding (but still I cannot catch what happens over the entire domain).

Comment: @plus91: I'm not sure what you're saying here. If the case without padding is the correct one, then there is no more domain to explore (you are getting the full result, it's periodic); you can tile the cross-correlation image if you want a larger domain, but that's meaningless.

Comment: @Chris sorry for the late reply.  Basing on what you said in the previous kind reply, suppose that my image is 400x400, by applying the FFT without zero-padding I can get information till 200x200 px, but like you've said it's periodic. For example, how can I know the value of the correlation function at x=250 and y=250 ? (sorry for this trivial question, but I'm trying to improve my skills on this topic :) )

Comment: @plus91: in the 400x400 case, a shift of zero is at (200,200). A shift of 50 in both directions is at (200+50,200+50). A shift of 250 would be at 200+250, but that is larger than 400, so it wraps around and ends up at 200+250-400=200-150. So a shift of 250 and a shift of -150 are equivalent. This makes sense if you think of the cross-correlation of the infinitely repeated image. Tile the image in your head, and think about what happens as you shift a copy to the right, and how that corresponds to a different length shift to the left.

Comment: what you've explained makes sense for me and it is really useful! thank you a lot! in order to deep study what you've explained, can you kindly link me some references or give me some reference book? 
again, thanks a lot!:D

Comment: I learned this subject from a wonderful teacher, using the book [Oppenheim and Willsky](https://www.amazon.com/Signals-Systems-2nd-Alan-Oppenheim/dp/0138147574). It’s a good book, but I honestly don’t know how easy that is to learn without a teacher. Good luck!

Comment: i have been lucky because you've given to me some clues. Basing on your clues and the book that you've linked, i'll try to study the topic better! Thank you for helping me :)